# What is the link between subvaluationism and Buddhism?

Tags: buddhism, vagueness

Sorry for the indefinite question, but I am confused. I know and have read some research into Buddhism and paraconsistent logic: what is the link with that and *vagueness*?

> From the start, paraconsistent logics were intended in part to deal
> with problems of vagueness and the sorites paradox (Jaśkowski 1948
> [1969]). Some empirical evidence suggest that vagueness in natural
> language is a good candidate for paraconsistent treatment (Ripley
> 2011).
>
> A few different paraconsistent approaches to vagueness have been
> suggested. Subvaluationism is the logical dual to supervaluationism:
> if a claim is true on some acceptable sharpening of a vague predicate,
> then it is true. Where the supervaluationist sees indeterminacy, or
> truth-value gaps, the subvaluationist sees overdeterminacy,
> truth-value gluts. A subvaluation logic will, like its
> supervaluational dual, preserve all classical tautologies, as long as
> the definition of validity is restricted to the non-glutty cases.

If a subvaluationist and paraconsistent treatment of vagueness showed that the Buddha exists, would the Buddha then exist or does it depend on whether or not subvaluationism is the best and only correct treatment of vagueness?

> Overlapping cases of truth and falsity are sometimes called truth
> "gluts" and so dialetheism is also sometimes called glut theory

Nagarjuna is often interpreted as using weak dialethism, using logic without LNC but not holding contradictory claims at the once, and there is some research into Madhyamaka as (ontic) vagueness. So could the history of Buddhism be interpreted as saying (among other things) that any quantification of certain (borderline) states of consciousness is also true of its [negation](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/102238/do-statements-about-borderline-cases-hold-for-both-the-vague-term-and-its-negati)? It would be odd, so I don't know.

Comment: i found some notes i read, and apparently Nagarjuna endorses a "weak dialetheism" (contradictory statements true but not at once), and perhaps that's all that can be said on this?

Comment: Gosh, subvaluationism sure sounds like how I approach life. It's effective, I guess. Perhaps the Buddha exists, for small values of 'Buddha'.

Comment: Even early [Buddhist logic](https://scholarworks.sjsu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1032&context=comparativephilosophy) recognizes "four valuations" (including both gaps and gluts), so neither sub nor super valuationism would fit it. Nagarjuna and his Madhyamaka school are even more complex, they deny all four ("*Being, non-being, being and non-being, neither being nor non-being: such is the method that the wise should always use*"). But logic of any sort cannot establish existence claims anyway.

Comment: what do you mean "logic... cannot establish existence claims", that all existence claims are based on the evidence of the senses unsupported by reason @Conifold ?

Comment: The exegesis, i.e. what Nagarjuna actually wants to say with his Madhyamaka and with the tretalemma seems to be a point of discussion between the experts. (1/2)

Comment: Good introductions are https://www.amazon.co.uk/Nagarjunas-Madhyamaka-Philosophical-Introduction-Westerhoff/dp/0195384962/ref=sr_1_2?Adv-Srch-Books-Submit.x=0&Adv-Srch-Books-Submit.y=0&__mk_en_GB=%C3%85M%C3%85Z%C3%95%C3%91&qid=1699933389&refinements=p_27%3AWesterhoff+Jan&s=books&sr=1-2&unfiltered=1 and https://www.amazon.co.uk/Fundamental-Wisdom-Middle-Way-Mulamadhyamakakarika/dp/0195093364/ref=sr_1_1?Adv-Srch-Books-Submit.x=0&Adv-Srch-Books-Submit.y=0&__mk_en_GB=%C3%85M%C3%85Z%C3%95%C3%91&qid=1699933444&refinements=p_27%3AGarfield+Jay&s=books&sr=1-1&unfiltered=1 (2/2)

Comment: i've read both of those @JoWehler therre are many interpretations of Nagarjuna, but one that shows that there is rebirth may be quite appealing, for obvious reasons